# Is it unnecessary to repeat Domain-Driven Design on a mobile back end?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm building a mobile app using Xamarin and I'm consuming services from a REST API. It is just extra and unnecessary work to follow a DDD pattern for the mobile app side? Should I just be making an application service layer to call from the controller and call it a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mobile application is responsible for just the view/presentation layer then I would suggest that DDD be used on the backend only. You can then expose domain behavior via webservices.